# Correct usage of 'sold out' and 'sold'

Tags: grammar

If a product is already sold and no longer available, do I say:

1. Sorry, the product has been 'sold' already.
2. Sorry, the product was 'sold' already.
3. Sorry, the product 'sold out' already.
4. Sorry, the product is 'sold out' already.
5. Sorry, the product has been 'sold out' already.

I'm slightly confused between the subtle differences between all the above statements. Can someone please clarify when do I use them?

Answer (score 3):

If you had just one of the item, "sold" is correct.
If you had a stock of them (more than one ready to be sold), and they are all gone, then the product is "sold out".
You can also say "We are sold out of that product."